# Why WinXP faster than Xubuntu under Virtualbox?

Tags: virtualbox

I have two VMs configured identically (hardware wise), the only difference is that the Windows XP one is uber fast and the Xubuntu very slow. I know this is an open ended question, but would anyone have any hunches on why?

Comment: How did you benchmark your system performance?

Comment: after 2 months xp would get slower, and what is more, try to see even now how the latest versions of Firefox or Chrome fare on the two systems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a fresh install of XP (without updates, antivirus and everything else you need) then it will seem very fast compared with Xubuntu.

The minimum & recommended RAM for Xubuntu are 256mb & 512mb, which is 4 time more than XP.

Lubuntu would provide similar performance to XP.